# Can Kafka FileSink FileStream Connector write files hourly?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am trying to write file Sink connector that will consume topic messages and write them to hourly files .I can not find any configuration for [File-sink Connector](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/filestream_connector.html#filesink-connector) .

Comment: The FileStreamSinkConnector is just designed as an example connector and not for production use. What's your use-case for writing hourly files? FWIW a lot of the time using a flat file is a 'code smell' that the integration/consumption of data should be done a different way (e.g. direct consumption from Kafka).

Comment: Hi Robin,
I am consuming data from kafka topic and then do some enrichment to those messages.
What is the approach for writing those messages it to files (every hour or even every minute).

Comment: So you're consuming the data from Kafka, enriching it, and then want to write it to hourly files? Or you're consuming from files to do the enrichment?

Comment: I am consuming from kafka topic then do the enrich and then need to write the enriched messages into files .

Comment: But what happens to the data once it's in the files? What process/system is consuming them?

Comment: We have another process that will transfer those files to another machines.

Comment: And what happens to them on the other machines?

Comment: HDFS Sink can be setup without Hadoop to write to local hourly directories, but I suspect there's a better solution for what you're trying to do

Comment: @cricket_007 Can you please add more information how can i start with the HDFS Sink Solution ?

Thanks